# Using API in IntelliJ Java to get live exchange rates

Tags: java, api, currency, converters

I am trying to create a currency converter using GUI, however the API part, where I need to get the live rates doesn't seem to work and throws an error when I try to compile it.
This is my code:
`

```
import java.io.*;
import okhttp3.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.apilayer.com/currency_data/convert?to=BGN&from=USD&amount=1")
                .addHeader("apikey", "R2EQE6ev2c2KWFR0GID6lKqvGFD4nrP2")
                .method("GET", null)
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response.body().string());
}
}
```

And this is the error that I am getting when I try to run the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okio/BufferedSource
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:51)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.java:126)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okio.BufferedSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 3 more
```

When I run it in the browser using the Live Demo option, everything works fine, but when I run it in my IntelliJ it shows an error. I also replaced } in .method("GET", }) with .method("GET", null) s0 it would let me to compile the program.

Comment: Your Intellij IDEA module for your app is not configured properly. You did not specify the dependency that contains class `okio.BufferedSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar files containing the required classes (and all their dependencies) to the project.
On Windows F4->Modules->Dependencies->+